# window.postMessage to iframe with null origin

Tags: javascript, iframe, postmessage

For testing purposes, i'm coding nested iframes :

main window > iframe > iframe

both iframes have a Blob as src, sandbox attribute with "allow-scripts" only.

it's easy to postMessage from first iframe to main window, but how can I postMessage from second iframe to first iframe since the origin is "null" ?

of course it's working if I set the second postMessage argument to "*", but it is a very bad practice.

any clue ?

Comment: I was playing with nested iframes, pages content generated with JS, no server involved.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was looking at the question. My mistake. I'll delete my earlier comment and retract my close vote.